# UWP view initializing before the controls load because another views threads are not completely closed

Tags: c#, mvvm, uwp, uwp-xaml

**UPDATE**

The IsLocked property for the pivot at the end of the ShowDetailPage is interfering with the loading of the controls for some reason or another.
I have 2 parent tabs, and for each tab one child tab could be created and when its created the child is locked. The child tab is added next to the parent tabs index.

I have a UWP application with pivot a controlled menu system. We have a top level and a second level. Within the second level some screens will create a view through a button command to go into a add/edit view that is locked until the closed button is clicked which brings it back to its parent menu screen.

For some reason when I close an add/edit view, some threads are not closing right away, and it's taking time to close a few threads. This creates a issue when trying to go into another parent tabs Add/edit view. Basically the view is initialized before the controls are even loaded.

The method ShowDetailPage is what I use in a button command on a view to open a add/edit view. The CloseDetailPage method is how we leave the screen. The indicator that tells me that this is a threading issue it that, the page transfer error only occurs when my controls property "Initialized" is set to true before entering the screen. (When it transfers correctly the property is false). Also if i watch the diagnostics output, If i wait a short amount of time, i will see a few threads close after i close the view, and then the initialized property is always false, and i'm able to move around correctly.

This is the pattern I notice when creating the error, and getting around it.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2hRP.jpg
These theads close shortly after I close a add/edit screen. Only if these close can i correctly transfer to another add/edit view.

What can I do to find out what threads are causing the issue?(I can see the memory location, but not the thread when the threads close.)

If I can find the threads, what could I do to wait for the threads to close before allowing a screen to be transferred to?

**NavigationUtility that handles the showing and closing of new screen.**

```
 internal static void ShowDetailPage(long customerId, BaseControl control, string parentPageTitle, string detailPageTitle)
    {
        try
        {
            Pivot p = MainPage.GetPivot();
            Utility u = new Utility();
            for (int i = 1; i < p.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                long customerIdFromPivot = (((p.Items[i] as PivotItem).Content) as Menus).ParentCustomer.CustomerId;
                if (CustomerIdFromPivot == CustomerId)
                {
                    var topMenuItem = (((p.Items[i] as PivotItem).Content) as Menus).GetPivot();
                    if (TopLevelPivots.ContainsKey(CustomerId))
                    {
                        TopLevelPivots[CustomerId] = topMenuItem;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        TopLevelPivots.Add(CustomerId, topMenuItem);
                    }
                    TopLevelPivots[CustomerId].IsLocked = true;
                    SearchInVisualTree(topMenuItem, CustomerId, parentPageTitle);
                    var submenus = SecondLevelPivots[CustomerId].ItemsSource;
                    ObservableCollection<MenuItem> addedMenus = new ObservableCollection<MenuItem>();
                    int index = 0;
                    foreach (var subMenuItem in submenus as IEnumerable<MenuItem>)
                    {
                        addedMenus.Add(subMenuItem);
                        if (subMenuItem.HeaderTitle == parentPageTitle)
                        {
                            if (DetailScreenParentIndex.ContainsKey(CustomerId))
                                DetailScreenParentIndex.Remove(CustomerId);
                            DetailScreenParentIndex.Add(CustomerId, index);
                            addedMenus.Add(new MenuItem() { HeaderTitle = detailPageTitle, Content = u.GetInitializedControl(control, control.ParentCustomer, addedMenus.Count), ParentCustomer = control.ParentCustomer });
                        }
                        index++;
                    }

                    SecondLevelPivots[CustomerId].ItemsSource = addedMenus;
                    //if (DetailScreenParentIndex.ContainsKey(CustomerId))
                    SecondLevelPivots[CustomerId].SelectedIndex = DetailScreenParentIndex[CustomerId] + 1;
                    //else
                    //    SecondLevelPivots[CustomerId].SelectedIndex = 0;
                    SecondLevelPivots[CustomerId].IsLocked = true;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }

    }

 internal static void CloseDetailPage(long CustomerId, string currentPage, string gotoPage)
    {
        try
        {
            Pivot p = MainPage.GetPivot();
            Utility u = new Utility();
            for (int i = 1; i < p.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                long CustomerIdFromPivot = (((p.Items[i] as PivotItem).Content) as Menus).ParentCustomer.CustomerId;
                if (CustomerIdFromPivot == CustomerId)
                {
                    var topMenuItem = (((p.Items[i] as PivotItem).Content) as Menus).GetPivot();
                    if (TopLevelPivots.ContainsKey(CustomerId))
                    {
                        TopLevelPivots[CustomerId] = topMenuItem;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        TopLevelPivots.Add(CustomerId, topMenuItem);
                    }
                    TopLevelPivots[CustomerId].IsLocked = false;
                    SearchInVisualTree(topMenuItem, CustomerId, gotoPage);
                    var submenus = SecondLevelPivots[CustomerId].ItemsSource;
                    ObservableCollection<MenuItem> addedMenus = new ObservableCollection<MenuItem>();
                    foreach (var submenuItem in submenus as IEnumerable<MenuItem>)
                    {
                        if (submenuItem.HeaderTitle != currentPage)
                        {
                            addedMenus.Add(submenuItem);
                        }
                    }
                    SecondLevelPivots[CustomerId].ItemsSource = addedMenus;
                    SecondLevelPivots[CustomerId].SelectedIndex = DetailScreenParentIndex[claimantId];
                    SecondLevelPivots[CustomerId].IsLocked = false;
                    SecondLevelPivots.Remove(CustomerId);
                    TopLevelPivots.Remove(CustomerId);
                    DetailScreenParentIndex.Remove(CustomerId);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Utility.LogError(ex);
        }
    }
```

**ViewModel** Command for button click to go to new screen.

```
private void AddCustomerCommandExecute(object obj)
    {
        bool bEditing = false;
        AddEditCustomer control = new AddEditCustomer();
        control.ParentCustomer = ParentCustomer;
        CustomerDetails customerDetail = obj as CustomerDetails ;
        if (customerDetail == null)
        {
            customerDetail = new CustomerDetails() { };
        }
        customerDetail.Customer = ParentCustomer;
        control.CustomerDetailsForAddEdit = customerDetail;
        customerDetail.IsEdit = bEditing;
        control.PropertyChanged += CustomersForAddEdit_PropertyChanged;
        Utility u = new Utility();
        NavigationUtility.ShowDetailPage(ParentCustomer.customerId, u.GetInitializedControl(control, ParentCustomer, 0), "Customers", "Add Customer");

    }
```

**View code behind for screen that gets shown for add/edit**

```
public sealed partial class AddEditCustomer : BaseControl
{
    public AddEditCustomerVM Model { get; set; }
    public CustomerDetails CustomerDetailsForAddEdit
    {
        get { return (CustomerDetails )GetValue(CustomerDetailsForAddEditProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(CustomerDetailsForAddEditProperty, value);
            OnPropertyChanged("CustomerDetailsForAddEdit");
        }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CustomerDetailsForAddEditProperty =
      DependencyProperty.Register("CustomerDetailsForAddEdit", typeof(CustomerDetails), typeof(AddEditCustomer), null);

    public AddEditCustomer()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        var resource = Resources.FirstOrDefault(aa => aa.Key.ToString() == "AddEditCustomerVM");
        if (resource.Value != null)
        {
            Binding b = new Binding();
            b.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
            b.Path = new PropertyPath("CustomerDetailsForAddEdit");
            b.Source = (resource.Value as AddEditCustomerVM);
            Model = (resource.Value as AddEditCustomerVM);
            this.SetBinding(CustomerDetailsForAddEditProperty, b);
            (resource.Value as AddEditCustomerVM).PropertyChanged += AddEditView_PropertyChanged;
            Binding bindVal = new Binding();
            bindVal.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
            bindVal.Path = new PropertyPath("ParentCustomer");
            bindVal.Source = (resource.Value as AddEditCustomerVM);
            this.SetBinding(ParentCustomerProperty, bindVal);
        }
    }
    private void AddEditView_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        OnPropertyChanged(e.PropertyName);
    }

    private void dpStartDate_DateChanged(CalendarDatePicker sender, CalendarDatePickerDateChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (dpEndDate.Date.HasValue)
        {
            if (args.NewDate.Value > dpEndDate.Date.Value)
                dpEndDate.Date = null;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: All the control render in the UI thread in uwp. Have  you invoke `ShowDetailPage` in UI thread?

Comment: I invoke the 'ShowDetailPage' in the view model. I updated my code shown above with the command that calls the 'ShowDetailPage', and the code behind for the view to be shown.

Comment: When the basecontrol size is changed on the window, the controls will appear.I'm lost.